# Design patterns for social networking site like facebook?

Tags: facebook, design-patterns, social-networking

I am interested in understanding the design principals to use to create the backend for a social networking site. I read up a few resources and found that facebook uses a graph as an underlying data structure where each node could be user/page/album etc. However, just that does not give me a top level view (block diagram or class diagram) on how to go about implementing a few basic features like (all using the graph data structure):

1. Adding/removing friends
2. News feed
3. Messaging

Any pointers on any resources would be great. I am also interested in finding out if a design pattern exists for a social networking site.

Please note that I am not looking for any language specific solution

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014475/social-networking-backend-architecture)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168828/architecture-of-social-networking-platforms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701850/social-networking-framework-for-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153941/social-networking)?

Please do a search on SO and you will land with many more! None seem conclusive but that's more to do with the nature of your question!

**EDIT:** You may find this [linked in architecture presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/linkedin/linkedins-communication-architecture) useful!

Comment: I went through all those posts before asking my question. I want to figure out this problem more from a data structure and design point of view. Since I am new to this domain, all I got from most of those was not to use a relational database

Comment: Ideally also a top level view of the various components and how they come together. I can then go and read about each of these components in detail.

Comment: @smitten11: Just edited the answer to include the top level view of the various components for linked social community site!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **Observer Design Pattern**, I think it is the base of Twitter, Facebook to publish things at the time line of other people that follow someone.

Maybe these book can help you
http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/patterns/Main_Page

Here you can find a lot of good information about soial Design Pattern
http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

Comment: That Social Interface Design Pattern book is along the right lines. Thanks.